# How to build ubuntu touch for unofficial cyanogenmod device

Tags: ubuntu-touch, compiling, samsung, porting

I own a Samsung galaxy scl i9003 and I would like to port Ubuntu touch on this device. We don't have an official cyanogenmod, but we have an unofficial version of it. I did the built of the unofficial cyanogenmod 10.1 but now I don't know how to proceed, and from where start following the porting guide to create a Ubuntu touch build flashable to my device. 
Please, I hope someone could help me 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your well on the way...

As mentioned here:

[How do I go about porting Ubuntu Touch to different devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350558/how-do-i-go-about-porting-ubuntu-touch-to-xyz-device)

Use this Guide:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Porting#Building_the_Android_pieces

You will need for development any 64-bit Desktop version of Ubuntu between 12.04 LTS and 13.10, the more ram the better.