# Install OS on Micromax A92 Device

Tags: system-installation

How to Install OS on Micromax A92 Mobile Device.
What I need?

I have A92 mobile device and I want to change the OS. But the tools required for it and the compatibility test for device is not known to me. Had any one tried it?

Or please guide me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support). That is the link for the compatibility info. For information about porting Ubuntu Touch to your phone see: [How do I go about porting Ubuntu Touch to different devices?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/350558/how-do-i-go-about-porting-ubuntu-touch-to-different-devices).

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Touch OS can offer to install for such selected devices, If you do install for your device it's totally on your own risk.[I suggest you to buy Nexus 7].

Ubuntu Phone suggest following devices to install Ubuntu Touch OS,

> Nexus 4
>
> Nexus 10
>
> Nexus 7 2013 WiFi
>
> Galaxy Nexus
>
> Nexus 7

The installation steps shown in this [link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install).

And to know about status for selected devices [click here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArLs7UPtu-hJdDZDNWliMmV1YUJ3Zk1pQlpDdGp4VFE&usp=sharing#gid=0).

To know how to get Ubuntu Phone [register here](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/register).