# Is it possible to install Ubuntu Touch on Galaxy S3 mini

Tags: ubuntu-touch, samsung

I know it is not on the list of supported devices, but I would like to know if it is at all possible to install Ubuntu Touch on the Samsung Galaxy S3 MINI. I am tired of the bogged down interface of the Android installed by Samsung and would love to try out a new OS on my phone. I love the lay out of Ubuntu Touch and badly want to try it. Any help is much appreciated! (the phone is a AT&T phone)

Note:
I am clearly stating that I know it is not on the list of supported devices. I want to know it the listed S3 process will work, or if there is any way to install even though it is not supported.

"I know it is not on the list of supported devices, but..." - The very first line in the question. Any help is appreciated!

This is not a duplicate because I know that this phone is not on the list that the page question will lead me too. I'm asking that if since the full version of this phone is on the list if it can be installed the same way on this phone. If not, is there any way I can try to manually install it?

Comment: This is not at all a duplicate. This was a legiminate question. I know the S3 MINI is not on the list on the Ubuntu that question will lead me to. As I said before, I want to know if you can install without it being on the list.

Comment: Did you read the entire answer? If your phone is not listed [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices) it isn't supported. You'll have to [port it yourself](http://askubuntu.com/questions/350558/how-do-i-go-about-porting-ubuntu-touch-to-different-devices).

Comment: I don't think we can answer if you can run a S3 ROM on the S3 mini, but we *certainly* cannot answer it without the *exact* model number of your phone. My guess is no. One more thing, why not just install a new interface over Samsung's?

Comment: Sorry, it was very ignorant of me to not post the model number, here it is: SAMSUNG-SM-G730A @Seth

Comment: yeah I'm pretty sure you can't use the GSIII images for that, too much difference. The mini has a 4 inch screen, different camera, different radio and different processor, for example.