# Can you run Ubuntu on an HP Slatebook?

Tags: android

The HP Slatebook runs Android 4.3 Jelly Bean. I wanted to get a new laptop to run Ubuntu on, and since this one doesn't run windows, it's cheaper. I wasn't sure if because it ran a tablet-like Android OS I was still going to be able to run Ubuntu on there because of it. I'm new to Ubuntu and I would like to know before I buy the laptop.

Comment: Most likely, no, at least not easily, but we would need hardware specs to answer.

Comment: I dont know what you need so heres the Amazon link with everything  http://www.amazon.com/HP-Slatebook-14-Inch-Touchscreen-Android/dp/B00KB3K6G4/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top?ie=UTF8  Thanks!

Comment: It's Nvidia Tegra4, and a quick search turns up [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21031/linux-on-a-tegra-tablet-for-programming). In short, there is no ready-made Ubuntu image for it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I go about porting Ubuntu Touch to different devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350558/how-do-i-go-about-porting-ubuntu-touch-to-different-devices)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to add Ubuntu by using the following Android apps

[Xserver](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=x.org.server&hl=en)

[Linux Deploy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.meefik.linuxdeploy)

I have not tried it myself yet because I am still waiting for the Slatebook to arrive.