# Ubuntu Phone for Nokia x2 Dual Sim

Tags: nokia

Is it possible to create a Ubuntu Phone ROMs for Nokia X Family (launched in 2014)? It would be really helpful since Microsoft isn't giving any updates.

Comment: Hmm you are skipping a step: 1st you need working firmware (ie. Linux modules) and that is off topic on Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not listed in supported devices or [ports in progress](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices).  To answer the "Is it possible" part - yes it might be possible. Read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350558/how-do-i-go-about-porting-ubuntu-touch-to-different-devices) to know how and keep a watch on the [XDA forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2344414).