# Where is the guide to port Ubuntu touch to cyanogenmod based devices?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, porting

[This guide](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/porting-new-device/) on developer.ubuntu.com tells how to port ubuntu to android based devices. It also mentions

> Note that this guide focuses on porting to devices present in the AOSP tree and **another version will focus on CyanogenMod** based ports.

But I can't find any link to the CyanogenMod guide. It does have a link to [this cyanogemod wiki page](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc:_porting_intro), but seems to be about porting CM to a phone rather than porting Ubuntu to CM based phone. Even [this link](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc%3a_Building_Basics) provided in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/362216/184942) does not seem to help.

So where exactly is the guide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The CyanogenMod based guide doesn't exist yet.**

David Callé (who write the first guide) is busy at the moment with other projects. When I talked to him last time (~one month ago) he said it will take care during the summer to do the CyanogenMod guide.

Please note that this is only indicative, and I don't know if and when this guide will be created.

Comment: So is there anything, anywhere that could help even a little?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/AndroidDevel) is something CyanogenMod related Bulid of Ubuntu touch.