# Porting Ubuntu Touch to a official cyanogenmod 11 or 12?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, porting

I have HTC Desire 816 (codename a5) and want to port Ubuntu touch to it.
Unfortunately I don't have AOSP device tree for a5 but i have CM device tree.
I tried to follow with the https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/porting-new-device/ but after adding my device tree and starting lunch i got a error:

```
build/core/product_config.mk:222: *** Can not locate config makefile for product "a5"
```

Could you please help with this issue? Or provide with the link how to port Ubuntu Touch to the CM based devices?
I have checked [How do I go about porting Ubuntu Touch to different devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350558/how-do-i-go-about-porting-ubuntu-touch-to-different-devices) but i think it is not clear for me. I have stopped on step from official porting guide. I started Lunch and selected my newly created device tree. I'm not sure why lunch can't find makefiles and which makefiles it tried to find.