# Can I install Ubuntu touch on any tablet?

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-touch

I have found this procedure for installing Ubuntu touch:

http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/linux/how-install-ubuntu-touch-image-3531970/

I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work with any device.

1. Is it risky? Does it work? If not, why?
2. Why is there no instruction on Ubuntu's website about how to install touch on a tablet?
3. And more generally, is it or not possible to install Ubuntu touch on any device? If not, will it ever be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "Can I install Ubuntu touch on any tablet?"

No

> "I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work with any device."

There are a myriad of reasons, like different screens, chips, RAM etc, the same reasons you must have Android built for that specific device, not just any old Android rom.

> "Is it risky? Does it work? If not, why?"

Yes it is, there is the same risks as flashing anything, bootloop, brick etc... See answer above for the why.

> "Why is there no instruction on Ubuntu's website about how to install
>   touch on a tablet?"

[There are](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/)

> "And more generally, is it or not possible to install Ubuntu touch on
>   any device? If not, will it ever be?"

It will never be possible to just install on any device, not all devices are created equally and compatibility is a big issue. More devices will get support in the future but never everything.

Although, if you have exceptional programming skills, you could in theory port it to any device but it would be a lot of work.

Info on [porting touch to your device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350558/how-do-i-go-about-porting-ubuntu-touch-to-different-devices) and [currently supported devices](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices), plus [3rd party roms](http://forum.xda-developers.com/ubuntu-touch/android-ports) on XDA.

Comment: OK, so I guess you highly discourage me to install it unless the device is specifically mentioned on the supported devices list?

Comment: Yes and even then, it will unlikely be 100%, it is early days for touch. There are many ports but they all lack features. If you can get a rom, go for it but you need root and at least clockworkmod on your device, look around XDA, I had a galaxy tab and it could do a dual boot with Touch and Android, I don't know what device you have but if it is common you may find a good bit of a community working on it.