# Touch on Surface Book

Tags: 17.04, touchscreen, surface

**How can I make touch work on my Surface Book?**

About my Surface Book:

- *Model:* Intel Core i7-6600 U @ 2.60 GHz with 8 GB Ram and Nvidia GPU
- *OS:* Ubuntu 17.04 Latest, kernel 4.10.0-13-generic

System outputs on Ubuntu:

```
~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                              id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                    id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳  USB OPTICAL MOUSE                            id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Surface Keyboard Consumer Control   id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Surface Keyboard Touchpad           id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                             id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                   id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                     id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Surface Pro 3/4 Buttons                       id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Surface Keyboard Keyboard           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Surface Keyboard Consumer Control   id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

System information on Windows:

[image: loaded drivers]

[image: IRQs]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I go about porting Ubuntu Touch to different devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350558/how-do-i-go-about-porting-ubuntu-touch-to-different-devices)

Answer (score 0):

I've run into quite a few issues regarding touch screen with Ubuntu on All-in-one devices. Here's a [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/SurfaceLinux/comments/4t64zt/getting_the_sp4_running_with_ubuntu_1604/d5q48d5/) concerning touch screen on a SP4 with Ubuntu 16.04. For all intents and purposes the process should be the same on 17.04, but due to the fact that Ubuntu 17 is still in Beta, support for that may be somewhat limited.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, it was a try. I could follow the instructions and boot from kernel `4.9.0-rc8-mssp4+`. Touch devices are still not found or working. Also shutdown is not working with this kernel (kernel panic).