# Ubuntu 19.04 on a Microsoft Laptop - Keyboard & Touchscreen issues

Tags: keyboard, 19.04, touchscreen, microsoft

I just installed Ubuntu 19.04 from a USB-Stick to my Microsoft Laptop and I noticed that my Keyboard doesn't work (during the installation & afterwards). While installing I just plugged in a USB-Keyboard, but I would like to be able to use the internal keyboard. The same goes for the Touchscreen (doesn't work at all).

I have seen a post about a similar issue but for Linux 18:
[Installed Ubuntu 18.04 on Microsoft Surface Book, and keyboard does not work. (only external keyboard)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1110346/installed-ubuntu-18-04-on-microsoft-surface-book-and-keyboard-does-not-work-o)

Hope someone can help me out here.

Thank you!
Jakob

Comment: Related: [Touch on Surface Book](https://askubuntu.com/questions/894222/touch-on-surface-book/896567)