# About supported devices under ubuntu touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I am a fan of ubuntu operating system. I have been using ubuntu as my pc OS from a last few years. I had heard that ubuntu had also launched the Os for mobile phones named ubuntu touch. I have a mobile phone named Micromax Canvas Doodle 3. But when I installed ubPorts installer , I did not find its name. Can you please tell , If there is other way of installing it on my phone. Do Ubuntu Touch is made only made for a fixed a number of mobile phones ?of which my phone is not a part of.

Answer (score 1):

The support of devices is created one-by-one and not every device is supported.

While Ubuntu Touch is considered a comminuty-project as a whole, there are some devices that are considered to have "official" status because they are maintained directly by the UBports team. Those devices are listed on the [Ubuntu Touch devices page](https://devices.ubuntu-touch.io/).

In the case of your device, it isn't listed on the page, which means you will have to go for an "unofficial" image at most (essentially, an immage that a member of the community put together, with *no* support from the UBports team).
One possible source for those images (while the forum is mainly focused on Android) would be [XDA-Developers](https://forum.xda-developers.com).

Worst case would be that nobody made an image for your phone and you'd have to put it together yourself. However, that might be a complicated process and a guide or step-by-step list of instructions can't easily be made. Two sources of information would be the [official page about porting](https://docs.ubuntu.com/phone/en/devices/porting-new-device) and [this AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350558/how-do-i-go-about-porting-ubuntu-touch-to-different-devices).
Also, XDA-Developers would help a lot here as well, since getting Android/CyanogenMod/LineageOS to run on your device is apparently considered an important step in porting Ubuntu Touch.

EDIT: Assuming that the "Micromax Canvas Doodle 3" is also known as "Micromax A102", [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/micromax-a102) is the device-specific XDA subforum for your device, where you might obtain a base-ROM for starting development or maybe even an unofficial build of Ubuntu Touch.

Answer (score 0):

UBports (the living fork of Ubuntu touch) is currently available for the devices listed on https://devices.ubuntu-touch.io/

Your device is indeed not supported. You could try to port your device, provided there is a working LineageOS build for it, but it is not exactly a trivial task to do.