# Install ubuntu on Lenovo tab m8, m7 and use OTG host

Tags: usb, printing, ubuntu-touch, lenovo, tablet

1. **Is it possible to install linux, so ubuntu or ubuntu touch (i don't know what's differences?) on lenovo tab m8 or lenovo tab m7 ?**
2. **And i would like to know if it's possible with the USB OTG to
   recognize this tablet like a printer ?**

More details: I want to connect this tablet with an other device, and when other device wants to print anything, it selects tablet (recognize like printer),tablet get the document to print and me from a program i can get the document and do my desired actions.
Thank you in advance

Comment: It would definitely be possible, but resources are scant at best.  I cant find anyone who's actually done it.  Firstly, you would have to root the device, then find an Linux image built for the M8, and finally flash the M8 with the new image.  I cant find any images already built for the M8.  My opinion is that this is not going to work the way you want because there is little to no Linux development for the M8. You could install Ubuntu inside Android, maybe something like https://userland.tech or https://andronix.app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I go about porting Ubuntu Touch to different devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350558/how-do-i-go-about-porting-ubuntu-touch-to-different-devices)

Answer (score 1):

Currently it's not possible to install Ubuntu Touch on those devices, because there's no port of Ubuntu Touch for them, and it's only possible to run Ubuntu Touch for devices that have received a port.

If you want to know the list of current ports, and their status, you should look at the [Ubuntu Touch devices web page](https://devices.ubuntu-touch.io/).