# How do I install Ubuntu Server 20.04 on a Ulefone S7 Pro (MT6580) Smartphone?

Tags: server, 20.04, android

I got a relatively old android smartphone on `arm v7`, I always wanted to turn the smartphone into a home server, I succeeded with `termux` and `proot-distro`, however I am limited in resources mainly because andoid keeps running in the background, even removing most of the system applications, I can not use all the smartphone resources. Also I don't have access to `systemctl, init` so I can't set my scripts to autorun, also the smartphone goes to sleep, which gives a significant delay when requesting the server. My smartphone is rooted and has TWRP recovery. Is there any way to install Ubuntu Server 20+ **INSTEAD** of android.

However, I can already see some problems that may arise. I will need a WIFI connection, I already set up a WIFI connection on my old laptop, but here I don't have a keyboard and I can't connect it because the USB port is damaged. So I will have to set up the system and ssh in advance on my pc. I have never done this and would appreciate it if I could at least know that it is possible.

I tried porting PostmarketOS, but I'm stuck on kernel selection

Smartphone: Ulefone S7 Pro (MT6580)

Comment: What's the phone? If the USB port is damaged, how do you charge it? If you can get the USB port working, you could use USB-OTG to USB female A, and connect that to a powered USB hub to connect a keyboard. Without knowing the phone we can't really give you more specific advice. The directions may vary based on the device. Also, are you fine with having Ubuntu Server in a chroot in Android, or do you want to run it natively?

Comment: I don't charge it, I connect it directly to a power source

Comment: Would you be fine with Debian instead of Ubuntu Server? They are pretty simaler? And would you be fine with a `chroot` from Android?

Comment: I have never worked with Debian, if there are no other options or it is much easier, then Debian is fine, as long as it works properly

Comment: Ubuntu is based on Debian, so most stuff is the same (networking is a bit different). More people have tried Debian, so it's a bit easier to figure out

Comment: It seems that what I need is `PostmarketOS`, but my device is not on the list of supported, and I can't port it, because I need to specify the repository of the kernel source code, alas I have not found it for my phone.

Comment: The big problem with Linux on phones is hardware compatibility. Laptops and Desktops and Servers use a fairly standardized set of components, and many of those component manufacturers contribute compatibility code to the Linux kernel. But phones can have strange/unusual architectures and proprietary hardware. Porting a Linux distro to phone hardware might be easy --or impossible-- depending upon those components.

Comment: @Danil You're welcome to try that (it might work), but from what I can tell it isn't Debian... there [are directions for porting to new devices](https://wiki.postmarketos.org/wiki/Porting_to_a_new_device), but IDK if it would work

Comment: @cocomac I actually tried this before, but as I wrote before, I got stuck on the kernel selection

Comment: You can also ask in the PostMarketOS forum.

Comment: Why are you all discussing this? Question is off topic as we do not provide assistance for hardware

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I go about porting Ubuntu Touch to different devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350558/how-do-i-go-about-porting-ubuntu-touch-to-different-devices)